# Generate dynamic text attribute by pattern

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, nsattributedstringkey

I have a string like this

```
var str = "This is &my& apple, I bought it %yesterday%"
```

Everything inside `& &` mark will be italics, inside `% %` mark will turn into bold style and set this data to a UILabel. The final output will be:

> This is *my* apple, I bought it **yesterday**

**Edited:** I am using `%(.*?)%` as a regex pattern to extract the substring

Is there any way to solve this issue? Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replacingOccurrences of regex to put the matches between bold and italic html tags and then use NSAttributedString to convert your html string to attributed string.

```
let str = "This is &my& apple, I bought it %yesterday%"

let html = str
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "(&.*?&)", with: "<b>"+"$1"+"</b>", options: .regularExpression)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "&(.*?)&", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "(%.*?%)", with: "<i>"+"$1"+"</i>", options: .regularExpression)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "%(.*?)%", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
```

---

Converting your html to attributed string

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 50)))
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
do {
    label.attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: Data(html.utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
} catch {
    print("error:", error)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It's working but showing me a warning about "+[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction", do you know what is it and how to silent it

Comment: @user3783161 I don't think thats related to the code above. Try isolating your issue and if you post a sample project I can take a look at it.

Comment: thanks for helping me, I figure out the problem and solved